# Injective map and surjective map between inductive limits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

I'm learning Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and trying to solve the following exercise: Exercise II.1.4

> Let $\phi: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of presheaves such that $\phi(U): \mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{G}(U)$ is injective for each $U$. Show that the induced map (on the sheafification) $\phi^{+}: \mathcal{F}^{+} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}^{+}$ is injective.

Note that there are bijections between the stalks $\mathcal{F}^{+}_p$ of the sheafification sheaf $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ and stalks $\mathcal{F}_p$ of the presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ for any $p \in X$, it suffices to show that $\phi$ is injective on stalks of the presheaves, i.e. $\phi_p :  \mathcal{F}_p \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_p $ is injective for all $p \in X$. This can be proved by direct verification.

Here I hope to generalize the discussion, and my question is **how to prove (or disprove)**:

> **Proposition**:  Let $I$ be a filtered preordered set, fix inductive systems $((X_i)_i, (\alpha_{ji})_{i \leq j})$ and $((Y_i)_i, (\beta_{ji})_{i \leq j})$ of sets, indexed by $I$, and let $X$ and $Y$ be their inductive limits. Let $(u_i: X_i \rightarrow Y_i)_i$ be a morphism of inductive systems and let $u:X \rightarrow Y$ be its inductive limit. **Show that** if there exists an $i \in I$ such that $u_j$ is injective (resp. surjective) for all $j \geq i$, then $u$ is injective (resp. surjective).

Since I worked out the Hartshorne's exercise by discussing the concrete stalks and germs instead of thinking on the "categorial" level, I find it hard to verify the above "Proposition". I'm also not familiar with the inductive limit of **morphisms of inductive systems**.

Could anyone prove the above proposition in details, or provide some references on these?

Moreover, does similar proposition holds for projective limits?

Thank you for your helps! :)

**P.S.** The proposition is adapted from Ulrich Gortz, Torsten Wedhorn's *Algebraic Geometry 1 - Schemes*.

Comment: The claim is true. There is a very concrete way to construct the inductive limit of an inductive system, and if you use this description the proof is easy. Actually, it should be the same as the proof for stalks of morphisms of presheaves with some words changed.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for your comments! With some minor changes, we can indeed get a proof for the general claim, by using the concrete way of construcing the inductive limits. I'm wondering if we can avoid the concrete constuction and prove this by using the universal property of the direct limits and someting like that.

Comment: No, this is not abstract nonsense, because it is false in other categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you a lot! So the proof actually depends on the concrete construction of the direct limit. So it at least holds in the categories (Set), (Grp), (Ring) and ($R$-mod) and so on, which have the "same" construction of direct limit as (Set). Is my understanding correct? I'm trying to find some counterexamples in other categories.

Comment: Yes. Almost all the categories (that I know of) in which the claim is true have finite limits and filtered colimits constructed the same way as in $\textbf{Set}$, or at least are left exact reflective subcategories of such categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you so much for your help!!